# return a list of matrices by applying if-else function by a sequence of conditions on a list of matrices

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, lapply

I have a list of matrices:

```
set.seed(100)
X1 <- mvrnorm(n=4, mu = rep(0, 5), Sigma = (matrix(1,5,5)+diag(5)))
X2 <- mvrnorm(n=4, mu = rep(0, 5), Sigma = (matrix(1,5,5)+diag(5)))
X3 <- mvrnorm(n=4, mu = rep(0, 5), Sigma = (matrix(1,5,5)+diag(5)))
X4 <- mvrnorm(n=4, mu = rep(0, 5), Sigma = (matrix(1,5,5)+diag(5)))
X <- list(X1,X2,X3,X4)
```

I have a sequence of threshold values

```
thresholds <- seq(from = 0.05, to = 0.95, by = 0.1)
```

I want a 0-1 list of the matrices, conditioning by each of the threshold values

I did this for one threshold value

```
lapply(X,function(x)(ifelse(x<thresholds[1],0,1)))
```

But I need to repeat this for the entire sequence of threshold values.
I am expecting a return of list of dim(4,5,4,10) [as no length(thresholds=10]

For one threshold value, my output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I want a list of 4 dimensions:
Displaying example with only the first 4 matrices out of 40 matrix slices:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0

, , 3, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0

, , 4, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: I edit my question trying to explain what I need exactly. TIA